# How to convert dictionary into SQL Query?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dictionary

I need to convert my python dictionary to sql query. Below is how my dictionary looks like

```
dict_info = {
    "Tables": [
        "product",
        "sales"
    ],
    "Columns": {
        "product": [
            "prod_id",
            "prod_desc",
        ],
        "sales": [
            "prod_id",
            "prod_sales",
            "prod_qty"
        ]
    },
    "Filter": {
        "region_id": "1,2",
        "state_id": "4,7,9",
        "store_id": "14",
    }
}
```

I am trying to make two different queries since there are two tables information.(if it is 3 tables, then I have to make 3 different queries.

What I need.

```
Query1= " SELECT product.prod_id, product.prod_desc FROM product WHERE product.region_id in 
          (1,2) AND product.state_id in (4,7,9) AND product.store_id in (14);

Query2= " SELECT product.prod_id, product.prod_sales, product.prod_qty FROM product WHERE
          sales.region_id in (1,2) AND sales.state_id in (4,7,9) AND sales.store_id in (14);
```

What I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

get_tables = dict_info.get("Tables", [])
get_columns = dict_info.get("Columns", [])

for i in tables:
    query = "SELECT " + ", ".join(columns[i]) + ' FROM ' + i ";"
```

Need help in how to put filter statements in the same query and creating dynamic queries for each of table selected.

Comment: Using `sqlalchemy` can make it easier

Comment: Using a library is also safer. Even though this not hard to do, I would hesitate to answer without knowing how this is used since using string interpolation to make SQL is a dangerous practice in many cases.

Comment: Hey @Mark, the use case is, I get this dictionary with body when people hit my API, based on the dictionary I need to convert dict to sql query so that I can run the sql query in the DB and get the result and return the same. But the dict can contain anything like agg, join, etc... Trying to create dynamic solution for this. Any sugggestions are welcome

Comment: You would really be much better off finding an existing query-building package to do this (pypika looks promising, though I haven't used it). Trying to do this with string concatenation is at high risk of SQL injection. Trying to craft something that will cover all possibilities is a very extensive task.

Comment: If this dict is coming from api users, this approach is dangerous. The accepted solution makes it trivial for someone to delete all your data. You absolutely should *not* do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by iterating over the tables and columns in your dictionary and appending the filter conditions on the end of each query:

```
def generate_sql_queries(dict_info):
    queries = []
    
    # Extracting filter conditions + formating them
    filters = dict_info.get("Filter", {})
    filter_conditions = []
    for column, values in filters.items():
        values = values.split(',')
        condition = f"{column} in ({','.join(values)})"
        filter_conditions.append(condition)
    filter_str = " AND ".join(filter_conditions)
    
    # Generating queries for tables
    tables = dict_info.get("Tables", [])
    columns_dict = dict_info.get("Columns", {})
    for table in tables:
        columns = columns_dict.get(table, [])
        columns_str = ', '.join([f"{table}.{col}" for col in columns])
        query = f"SELECT {columns_str} FROM {table} WHERE {filter_str};"
        queries.append(query)
    
    return queries

# Example use:
dict_info = {
    # your dictionary is here
}

queries = generate_sql_queries(dict_info)
for i, query in enumerate(queries, 1):
    print(f"Query{i} = \"{query}\"")
```

Answer (score 3):

**I tried this way to solve your problem :**

```
dict_info = {
    "Tables": ["Table1", "Table2"],
    "Columns": {
        "Table1": ["Column1", "Column2"],
        "Table2": ["Column3", "Column4"],
    },
    "Filter": {
        "Table1": {"Key1": [1, 2, 3], "Key2": [4, 5]},
        "Table2": {"Key3": [6, 7, 8]}
    }
}

tables = dict_info.get("Tables", [])
columns = dict_info.get("Columns", {})
filters = dict_info.get("Filter", {})

for table in tables:
    cols = ", ".join([f"{table}.{col}" for col in columns.get(table, [])])
    
    # Construct the WHERE clause for the current table
    filter_items = filters.get(table, {})
    where_clauses = []
    for key, values in filter_items.items():
        if values:  # Check if the list of values is not empty
            values_str = ', '.join(map(str, values))
            where_clauses.append(f"{table}.{key} IN ({values_str})")
    
    where = " AND ".join(where_clauses)
    
    query = f"SELECT {cols} FROM {table}"
    if where:
        query += f" WHERE {where};"
    else:
        query += ";"
    
    print(query)
```

Here, I used tests to make sure that empty lists or missing keys won't result in problems. To address situations when columns or filters might be missing for a certain table, the cols and where construction code has been changed.

**And your your output looks like :**

```
SELECT Table1.Column1, Table1.Column2 FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.Key1 IN (1, 2, 3) AND Table1.Key2 IN (4, 5);
SELECT Table2.Column3, Table2.Column4 FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.Key3 IN (6, 7, 8);
```